# Jest snapshot test - Error occurs when creating new object in componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, snapshot

I have a component whose root DOM element is a `<canvas>`. I use the componentDidMount() method to draw an image on the canvas; However, I am using a 3rd-party library, and when the test attempts to create a new object derived from that library, **I receive the following error during my test**:

`TypeError: QR is not a constructor`

`QR` is the name of the class used to instantiate the object from. Here is my component (note that when running the app, there is no error regarding the `QR` object, it only occurs during the test).

*QRCode.js*:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as QR from 'qrious';

export class QRCode extends Component {

    render(){
        return (
            <canvas className='QRCode'>
            </canvas>
        );
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.drawQRCode();
    }

    drawQRCode() {
        ...
        // the error is occuring here
        let qr = new QR({
            element: canvas,
            value: 'http://example.com/',
            size: canvasSize,
            level: 'H',
            foreground: '#2B2F2B'
        });
        ...
    }

}
```

*QRCode.test.js*:

```
import { QRCode } from './QRCode';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

describe('QRCode', () => {

    it('renders correctly (snapshot test)', () => {
        const tree = renderer
            .create(<QRCode />)
            .toJSON();

        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

});
```

I tried adding `import * as QR from 'qrious';` to the top of the *QRCode.test.js* file, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `import * as QR from 'qrious'` with `import QR from 'qrious'`

Edit:

Since `qrious` does not have default export, should be changed to:

`import { QRious } from 'qrious'`

or

`import { QRious as QR } from 'qrious'`

Comment: There is no default export in the qrious.js file, so it won't work that way unfortunately

Comment: In that case try `import { QRious } from 'qrious'` and use it as `new QRious()` or if you want to keep as QR: `import { QRious as QR } from 'qrious'`